# How to compare two date in Struts2 <s:if> tag in jsp

Tags: java, date, struts2, date-comparison

Hi i am trying to compare two date in Struts2 jsp page which i am not able to compare not getting proper result.

i am using following code to compare date:

```
<s:if test="%{day.equals(#request.curDate) == '0'}">
    exiqute code
</s:if>

<s:else>
    Exicute code
</s:else>
```

This is not working if any one can help me it would be great.

Comment: `%{day.equals(#request.curDate)}`..

Comment: Thanks but  i have tried this already not working

Comment: not working means what, what is `day` what about `curDate`, both contains same value or not..

Comment: its is same but exicuting  only Else part

Comment: include some more code to understand those variables 'day' and 'curDate'

Comment: day and curDate variable date type which set using bean class

Comment: Print both values using `<s:property>` tag.